# Inverse Limit in the category of $C^{\ast}$-algebras or operator spaces

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

> Does the inverse limits (Projective limits) exist in the category of $C^{\ast}$-algebras or operator spaces?

I tried to search but could not find a proper reference. Any reference or comments about this?

Comment: This is somewhat standard material for C*-algebras. Inverse limits are what category theorists just call "limits", so it suffices to construct products and equalizers. Equalizers are exactly the same as set-theoretic equalizers. The only unusual thing is infinite products: The infinite product of $(A_i)_{i \in I}$ consists only of sequences $a_i \in A_i$ such that $(\|a_i\|)_{i \in I}$ is bounded uniformly in $I$, so the C*-algebra product is strictly smaller than the set-theoretic product, but coincides with the $\ell^\infty$-direct sum.

Comment: I think the same is true *mutatis mutandis* in the category of operator spaces (with complete contractions as morphisms), although I did not check. The category of operator spaces with completely bounded maps as morphisms does not have infinite products.

Comment: Try "N. C. Phillips, Inverse limits of C*-algebras, Journal of Operator Theory, Vol. 19 (1988), 159-195".

Comment: @Ruy That article is about pro-C*-algebras, or cofiltered limits of C*-algebras in the category of locally convex algebras, such as $C(\mathbb{R})$ equipped with uniform convergence on compact sets, rather than on inverse limits in the category of C*-algebras as asked about in the question. But don't delete your comment - others may find the same article and it is useful to have this clarification.

Comment: @RobertFurber: is it obvious that category of os with morph cb maps does not have infinite product? Can you please explain

Comment: @Ruy I have seen that article but it was not helpful

Comment: @MathLover The proof I know is essentially the same as the proof that the category of Banach spaces and bounded maps does not have infinite products. Suppose for a contradiction that the infinite product of $\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}\C$ with itself countably many times existed ($\C \cong B(\C)$ is the operator space structure). There is a family of (completely) bounded maps $\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}} (f_n)_{n \in \N}$ from $\C \rightarrow \C$ defined by $f_n(x) = nx$. By using the product structure, you can then contradict $\| \langle f_n \rangle_{n \in \N}(1) \|$ being finite.